# Change background of JLabel in runtime using reflection

Tags: java, swing, reflection, jlabel

I need to change background of JLabels dynamically.

I've 70 JLabels in a class. All JLabels represent some specific items. The items names are same as the variable of JLabel. The Sold Items names are saved in database. If I run a query that will return an array of the sold items. The sold items that are same as the JLabel should change the background. Rest will not change.

I've got the variables of all fields like this:

```
  Field fld[] = BlueLine.class.getDeclaredFields();  
   for (int i = 0; i < fld.length; i++)  
   {
   System.out.println("Variable Name is : " + fld[i].getName());
   }
```

How can I cast my `fld` to a `JLabel` and change background of the JLabel when certain condition meets ? for example:

```
   if(fld[i] == label5){
   label5.setBackground.(Color.red);
   } // or something like this. ?
```

Any outline will help.

Comment: You cannot cast a field to a JLabel

Comment: That's correct It is impossible to cast a field to a JLabel. But is there any option so that I can get all the JLabels of a class and hold it in an array and do whatever i want. I just need to change the background of the labels.

Comment: Why can't you use an ActionListener if you want the text to change when a certain condition is met?

Comment: ActionListner will not work here. JLabel backgrounds will change dynamically. all JLabels represent some fixed items. User may sale any item. The sold items should change background.

Comment: It seems like I'm somehow missing the point of why you do not call `label.setBackground` ...

Comment: Do you have reference of parent(`JPanel`) of `JLabel` where it is added?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're just looking at the fields themselves - you're interested in the *values* of those fields. For example:

```
Object value = fld[i].get(target); // Or null for static fields
if (value == label5) {
    ...
}
```

Here `target` is a reference to the object whose fields you want to get the values from. For static fields, just use `null`, as per the comment.

It's not at all clear that all of this is a good idea, however - problems which *can* be solved with reflection are often *better* solved in a different way. We don't really have enough context to advise you of specifics at the moment, but I would recommend that you at least try to think of cleaner designs.

Answer (score 1):

Try it using `Jcomponent.putClientProperty()` and `Jcomponent.getClientProperty()`.

Steps to follow:

- First set the name of the `JLabel` same as its variable name
- Put it as client property of `JPanel` where `JLabel` is added
- Get it back using client property from `JPanel` using name of `JLabel`

Note: you can access it by using `Field.getName()` as defined in your question.

**Sample code :**

```
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.addContainerListener(new ContainerListener() {

        @Override
        public void componentRemoved(ContainerEvent e) {
            String name = e.getChild().getName();
            if (name != null) {
                System.out.println(name + " removed");
                panel.putClientProperty(name, null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e) {
            String name = e.getChild().getName();
            if (name != null) {
                System.out.println(name + " added");
                panel.putClientProperty(name, e.getChild());
            }
        }
    });

    MyLabels myLabels = new MyLabels();
    panel.add(myLabels.getProduct1());
    panel.add(myLabels.getProduct2());
    panel.add(myLabels.getProduct3());

    JButton btn = new JButton("Product1 and Product3 are sold");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String[] soldItems = new String[] { "Product1", "Product3" };

            for (String soldItem : soldItems) {
                Object obj = panel.getClientProperty(soldItem);
                if (obj instanceof JLabel) {
                    ((JLabel) obj).setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    panel.add(btn);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

**MyLabels.java:**

```
class MyLabels {
    private JLabel Product1;
    private JLabel Product2;
    private JLabel Product3;

    public MyLabels() {
        Product1 = new JLabel("Product1");
        Product1.setName(Product1.getText());

        Product2 = new JLabel("Product2");
        Product2.setName(Product2.getText());

        Product3 = new JLabel("Product3");
        Product3.setName(Product3.getText());
    }

    public JLabel getProduct1() {
        return Product1;
    }

    public void setProduct1(JLabel product1) {
        Product1 = product1;
    }

    public JLabel getProduct2() {
        return Product2;
    }

    public void setProduct2(JLabel product2) {
        Product2 = product2;
    }

    public JLabel getProduct3() {
        return Product3;
    }

    public void setProduct3(JLabel product3) {
        Product3 = product3;
    }

}
```